# Why can't I post questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am getting a notice when I click the "Ask question" button:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the
> Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

I just asked 8 questions, now I received this message.

Answer (score 6):

You actually asked 10 questions; 2 of them were deleted (you can find them [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/139150) - that link only works for you and for ♦ moderators). At some point in the past, you have received a warning when asking a question indicating that you were close to the limit, and apparently it kicked in now. There is nothing we can do about it, it's a feature of the system.

Please try to improve your current questions, especially the ones with a negative score, and hope that they get upvoted. That's about the only way out of it. Also check the guidance given in the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232)